Excel VBA Dialog box hiding some values
Below is part of the code I found that will list down all the sheets I have in the workbook as an option for the user to select and will assign the selected worksheet to ws2. Is it possible for me to hide/not show some of the sheets as an option for the user? Example: I have Sheet1 to Sheet10, when the dialog box display it will only show Sheet1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10.
        Const ColItems  As Long = 20
        Const LetterWidth As Long = 20
        Const HeightRowz As Long = 30
        Const SheetID As String = "__SheetSelection"
         
        Dim Y%, TopPos%, iSet%, optCols%, intLetters%, optMaxChars%, optLeft%
        Dim wsDlg As DialogSheet, objOpt As OptionButton, optCaption$, objSheet As Object
        optCaption = "": Y = 0
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets(SheetID).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Err.Clear
         
        Set wsDlg = ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets.Add
        With wsDlg
            .Name = SheetID
            .Visible = xlSheetHidden
            iSet = 0: optCols = 0: optMaxChars = 0: optLeft = 100: TopPos = 40
         
            For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
                If objSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                    Y = Y + 1
                    If Y Mod ColItems = 1 Then
                        optCols = optCols + 1
                        TopPos = 45
                        optLeft = optLeft + (optMaxChars * LetterWidth)
                        optMaxChars = 0
                    End If
                    intLetters = Len(objSheet.Name)
                    If intLetters > optMaxChars Then optMaxChars = intLetters
                        iSet = iSet + 1
                        .OptionButtons.Add optLeft, TopPos, intLetters * LetterWidth, 16
                        .OptionButtons(iSet).Text = objSheet.Name
                        TopPos = TopPos + 15
                    End If
            Next objSheet
            
            If Y > 0 Then
                '.Buttons.Left = optLeft + (optMaxChars * LetterWidth) + 24
                With .DialogFrame
                .Height = Application.Max(80, WorksheetFunction.Min(iSet, ColItems) * HeightRowz + 10)
                .Width = optLeft + (optMaxChars * LetterWidth)
                .Caption = "Select sheet"
                End With
                
                .Buttons("Button 2").BringToFront
                .Buttons("Button 3").BringToFront
                'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                
                If .Show = True Then
                    For Each objOpt In wsDlg.OptionButtons
                        If objOpt.Value = xlOn Then
                            optCaption = objOpt.Caption
                        ElseIf objOpt.Value = "General" Then
                        optCaption = ""
                    Exit For
                End If
                Next objOpt
            End If
             
            If optCaption = "" Then
                'Or optCaption = "Sheet2"
                MsgBox "You did not select a worksheet.", 48, "Cannot continue"
                If .Show = True Then
                    For Each objOpt In wsDlg.OptionButtons
                        If objOpt.Value = xlOn Then
                            optCaption = objOpt.Caption
                        ElseIf objOpt.Value = "General" Then
                            optCaption = ""
                    Exit For
                End If
                Next objOpt
            End If
            
            ElseIf optCaption = "Sheet1" Or optCaption = "Sheet2" Or optCaption = "Sheet6" Or optCaption = "Sheet7" Then
                MsgBox "Invalid", 48, "Cannot Continue"
            Exit Sub
            Else
            
            Set ws2 = Worksheets(optCaption)
            
            End If
            End If
        End With

Making changes to this part of the code works but not sure if it is effective.
            For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
                If objSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                    Y = Y + 1
                    If objSheet.Name <> "Sheet1" And objSheet.Name <> "Sheet2" And objSheet.Name <> "Sheet6" And objSheet.Name <> "Sheet7" Then
                        If Y Mod ColItems = 1 Then
                            optCols = optCols + 1
                            TopPos = 45
                            optLeft = optLeft + (optMaxChars * LetterWidth)
                            optMaxChars = 0
                        End If
                        intLetters = Len(objSheet.Name)
                        If intLetters > optMaxChars Then optMaxChars = intLetters
                            iSet = iSet + 1
                            .OptionButtons.Add optLeft, TopPos, intLetters * LetterWidth, 16
                            .OptionButtons(iSet).Text = objSheet.Name
                            TopPos = TopPos + 15
                        End If
                    End If
            Next objSheet


Don't add the ones you don't want to show.

Didn't you copy your existing code? If so, it could not work without raising an error, I'm afraid. It misses a End With... Then,  On Error Resume Next must be followed by On Error GoTo 0 after the part you consider it may raise an error. I would suggest to place it after Err.Clear. Besides that, a little indentation did not kill anybody, AFAIK. It only makes the code readable without unjustified effort.

Firstly, please repair the code as it is taking in consideration my above comment suggestions. Besides End With it also needs an End If code line.
Now, in order to iterate between a limited group of sheets there are more possibilities. To make a simple example I will firstly try using your construction, respectively:
Sub originalIterationWay()
   Dim objSheet As Object
   For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If objSheet.Name <> "Sheet1" And objSheet.Name <> "Sheet4" Then 'except these sheets
            Debug.Print objSheet.Name
        End If
   Next objSheet
End Sub

Such a way is feasible if there are not many sheets and you need to exclude a limited number of them.
When there are a lot of sheets on the workbook and you need to iterate between a limited number of them you can try the next ways:

Place the respective sheets names in an array and iterate only between these one:

Sub playWithSheetNamesArray()
  Dim arrSh: arrSh = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet5", "Sheet7")
    Dim objSheet As Object
    For Each objSheet In Worksheets(arrSh)
       Debug.Print objSheet.Name
    Next objSheet
End Sub

You need to load in the array the real name of the sheets you need to iterate between.

You can place in an array the sheets needed to be iterated index:

Sub playWithSheetsIndexesArray()
  Dim arrSh: arrSh = Array(1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10)
    Dim objSheet As Object
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrSh)
       Set objSheet = Worksheets(arrSh(i))
       Debug.Print objSheet.Name
    Next i
End Sub

In this case you can use the sheets indexes (their position, starting with one), independent of their name. I mean, if you will name "Sheet1" as "My First Sheet", it will return/use "My First Sheet" sheet.
Please, send some feedback after testing it. If something not clar enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

How would I use it in my code for example the first method you showed where I would exclude Sheet1 & 4. Right now, I would only be excluding Sheet1, 2, 6 & 7. So, if its 4 sheets, I would need to use the 2nd method you recommended? Btw i made some changes already hopefully it is clearer. Thank you

@user23357972 It should be simple, I think. That's why I also presented your way... In the first code you only add a new condition, based on the sheets to be excluded names.  In the others only must replace For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets with the model of the two testing subs.

Thanks for the help, managed to get it work using the first method you suggested but I will try the second method also to see how it will work.

@user23357972 Glad I could help! All three methods should work. But pay attention to what I wrote about each case... What it means and when it is good to be used.
